# mongodb - aggregation - $unwind $not

Tags: mongodb

I have a little problem with my aggregation in mongodb;

Collection uczelnia:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a5e404e6494620e7471c51a"), 
"uczelnia" : "Politechnika Czestochowska", 
"miasto" : "Czestochowa", 
"ulica" : "Armii Krajowej 1", 
"doktorzy" : [
    {
        "imie" : "Janina", 
        "nazwisko" : "Kowalska"
    }, 
    {
        "imie" : "Dorota", 
        "nazwisko" : "Janiak"
    }, 
    {
        "imie" : "Andrzej", 
        "nazwisko" : "Duda"
    }
]}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a5e40636494620e7471c51b"), 
"uczelnia" : "Politechnika Wroclawska", 
"miasto" : "Wroclaw", 
"ulica" : "Jodlowa 15", 
"doktorzy" : [
    {
        "imie" : "Jolanta", 
        "nazwisko" : "Kanar"
    }, 
    {
        "imie" : "Mateusz", 
        "nazwisko" : "Laskowski"
    }, 
    {
        "imie" : "Piotr", 
        "nazwisko" : "Potrzebny"
    }
]}
```

My aggregate:

```
 db.uczelnia.aggregate([{
$match: {$unwind: "$doktorzy.imie"{$not: /a$/}}},{
$group: {_id: "$doktorzy.imie", liczba_Pan:{$sum:1}}},{
$sort: { liczba_Pan: 1 }}]);
```

I want to find all of doctor(doktorzy) womens(last letter a in name) in a 
school(uczelnia).
imie(name)

Tell me what i make wrong here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your not able to do that in 1 unwind pipeline stage.
First action is unwinding the array, then matching and regroup.
I altered your aggregation to :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        $unwind: "$doktorzy"
    },
    {
        $match: {
        "doktorzy.imie" : { $regex : "a$", $options : "i"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {_id: "$doktorzy.imie", liczba_Pan:{$sum:1}}
    },
]);
```

The match is a regex ignoring case and matching imie ending on "a"